# how to use preventDefault() for specified form fields?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a task to use preventDefault() on a form I created before using HTML and CSS. I am not sure how to use preventDefault() and how to use it only for the fields my task asks.

The fields which need to go through the preventDefault() process are name, email address, address and postcode, the 'keep me informed' box is not checked.

```css
form{
    background-color: rgb(190, 231, 190);
    padding: 5pt;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width:30%;
    border: 1pt solid black;
}

legend{
    background-color: rgb(134, 97, 28);
    margin: auto;
    padding-inline: 20%;
    padding-top: 2pt;
    padding-bottom: 2pt;
    color: white;
}

fieldset{
    padding: 10pt;
}

#p1, #p3{
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5pt;
}

#p3{
    padding-left: 30%;
    padding-right: 25%;

}

#p3 input{
    background-color: rgb(134, 97, 28);
    border-radius: 7pt;
    color: white;
    padding: 5pt;
    width: 75pt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Topic 4, Exercise 4 (Miguel Divo)</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Shirt Order Form</legend>

                <p>
                    <label>Shirt Size</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <select name="shirt_size" >
                        <option>Choose Size</option>
                        <option>XS</option>
                        <option>S</option>
                        <option>M</option>
                        <option>L</option>
                        <option>XL</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Sleeves</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="radio" name="sleeve" value="1" >Short<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="sleeve" value="2" >Long<br>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Choose Shirt Colour</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="color" name="colourChoice" >
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Quantity</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="number" name="quantity" >
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Date Requested</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="date" name="date" >
                </p>
            </fieldset>
            <br>
            <fieldset>
                <p>
                    <label>Name</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="name" >
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Email</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="email" name="email" >
                </p>
                <p>Telephone Number</p>
                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" 
                    pattern="[4]{2}[-][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{4}" > Example: 44-207-882-1234
                </p>
            </fieldset>
            <br>
            <fieldset>
                <p>
                    <label>Address</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="address" >
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>City</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="city" list="cities" >
                        <datalist id="cities">
                            <option>Birmingham</option>
                            <option>Glasgow</option>
                            <option>London</option>
                            <option>Manchester</option>
                        </datalist>
                    </input>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Postcode</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="postcode" >
                </p>
            </fieldset>
            <br>

            <p id="p1">
                Please keep me informed about future shirt designs<input type="checkbox" name="accept">
            </p>
            <p id="p3">                    
                <input type="submit"> 
                <input type="reset" value="Clear Form">
            </p>

        </form>


        <script src="preventDefault.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. What is the actual usecase for the fields you mention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent form submission using preventDefault when the specific fields are not filled out

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const orderForm = document.getElementById("orderForm")
  orderForm.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    if (orderForm.querySelector("[name=accept]").checked) {
      const valid = ["name", "email", "address", "address", "postcode"]
        .filter(fieldName => orderForm.querySelector("[name=" + fieldName + "]").value === "").length === 0; // count empty
      if (!valid) {
        console.log("empty fields")
        event.preventDefault()
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```css
form {
  background-color: rgb(190, 231, 190);
  padding: 5pt;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30%;
  border: 1pt solid black;
}

legend {
  background-color: rgb(134, 97, 28);
  margin: auto;
  padding-inline: 20%;
  padding-top: 2pt;
  padding-bottom: 2pt;
  color: white;
}

fieldset {
  padding: 10pt;
}

#p1,
#p3 {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5pt;
}

#p3 {
  padding-left: 30%;
  padding-right: 25%;
}

#p3 input {
  background-color: rgb(134, 97, 28);
  border-radius: 7pt;
  color: white;
  padding: 5pt;
  width: 75pt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Topic 4, Exercise 4 (Miguel Divo)</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="orderForm">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Shirt Order Form</legend>

      <p>
        <label>Shirt Size</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <select name="shirt_size">
          <option>Choose Size</option>
          <option>XS</option>
          <option>S</option>
          <option>M</option>
          <option>L</option>
          <option>XL</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Sleeves</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="radio" name="sleeve" value="1">Short<br>
        <input type="radio" name="sleeve" value="2">Long<br>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Choose Shirt Colour</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="color" name="colourChoice">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Quantity</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="number" name="quantity">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Date Requested</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="date" name="date">
      </p>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <fieldset>
      <p>
        <label>Name</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="text" name="name">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Email</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="email" name="email">
      </p>
      <p>Telephone Number</p>
      <p>
        <input type="text" name="phone" pattern="[4]{2}[-][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{4}"> Example: 44-207-882-1234
      </p>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <fieldset>
      <p>
        <label>Address</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="text" name="address">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>City</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="text" name="city" list="cities">
        <datalist id="cities">
                            <option>Birmingham</option>
                            <option>Glasgow</option>
                            <option>London</option>
                            <option>Manchester</option>
                        </datalist>
        </input>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Postcode</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="text" name="postcode">
      </p>
    </fieldset>
    <br>

    <p id="p1">
      Please keep me informed about future shirt designs<input type="checkbox" name="accept">
    </p>
    <p id="p3">
      <input type="submit">
      <input type="reset" value="Clear Form">
    </p>

  </form>


  <script src="preventDefault.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

this can also be achieved by simply adding required on each of the tags in question

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const orderForm = document.getElementById("orderForm")
  orderForm.querySelector("[name=accept]").addEventListener("change", function() {
    const req = this.checked;
    ["name", "email", "address", "address", "postcode"].forEach(fieldName =>
      orderForm.querySelector("[name=" + fieldName + "]").required = req);
  })
})
```

```css
form {
  background-color: rgb(190, 231, 190);
  padding: 5pt;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30%;
  border: 1pt solid black;
}

legend {
  background-color: rgb(134, 97, 28);
  margin: auto;
  padding-inline: 20%;
  padding-top: 2pt;
  padding-bottom: 2pt;
  color: white;
}

fieldset {
  padding: 10pt;
}

#p1,
#p3 {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5pt;
}

#p3 {
  padding-left: 30%;
  padding-right: 25%;
}

#p3 input {
  background-color: rgb(134, 97, 28);
  border-radius: 7pt;
  color: white;
  padding: 5pt;
  width: 75pt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Topic 4, Exercise 4 (Miguel Divo)</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="orderForm">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Shirt Order Form</legend>

      <p>
        <label>Shirt Size</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <select name="shirt_size">
          <option>Choose Size</option>
          <option>XS</option>
          <option>S</option>
          <option>M</option>
          <option>L</option>
          <option>XL</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Sleeves</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="radio" name="sleeve" value="1">Short<br>
        <input type="radio" name="sleeve" value="2">Long<br>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Choose Shirt Colour</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="color" name="colourChoice">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Quantity</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="number" name="quantity">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Date Requested</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="date" name="date">
      </p>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <fieldset>
      <p>
        <label>Name</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="text" name="name">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Email</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="email" name="email">
      </p>
      <p>Telephone Number</p>
      <p>
        <input type="text" name="phone" pattern="[4]{2}[-][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{4}"> Example: 44-207-882-1234
      </p>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <fieldset>
      <p>
        <label>Address</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="text" name="address">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>City</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="text" name="city" list="cities">
        <datalist id="cities">
                            <option>Birmingham</option>
                            <option>Glasgow</option>
                            <option>London</option>
                            <option>Manchester</option>
                        </datalist>
        </input>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Postcode</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="text" name="postcode">
      </p>
    </fieldset>
    <br>

    <p id="p1">
      Please keep me informed about future shirt designs<input type="checkbox" name="accept">
    </p>
    <p id="p3">
      <input type="submit">
      <input type="reset" value="Clear Form">
    </p>

  </form>


  <script src="preventDefault.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much, i didn't know you can use require as a tag

Comment: I updated my answer since I now understood the question. I added the test to only look at the fields if the checkbox was checked. I will make a simpler version too

Comment: See updated answer to set the required when checked

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>ejemplo de preventDefault</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function stopDefAction(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<p>click on the box.</p>

<form>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="stopDefAction(event);"/>
<label for="checkbox">Select</label>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: this works, but how do i make it so that if the user doesn't enter anything in the fields i mentioned, it executes stopDefAction() ?